# Regex on Windows vs Mac

Tags: java, regex, macos

I have a string that I am splitting using Java. It works perfectly fine on my Windows machine, but not on my Mac (using Eclipse)

I have a string of text that contains single spaces and double spaces like so:

```
 August 05   July 09   May 07   April 01   March 19   February 19   January 15   December 17   December 04   December 03   December 02   November 24   October 30
```

I am splitting using

```
String monthAndDay[] = formattedNewsDates.split("\\s\\s");
```

Again, not sure why it is working on Windows but not Mac. Does one platform understand regular expressions a different way?

Comment: Are you sure that they are actual spaces (ASCII 32) and not some "blank" unicode character?

Comment: The "string" is being pulled from an external source. Is there some way I could find out which is there? Seems to me like it's actual spaces

Comment: Break it down to a `char` array and output there values (converting them to `int` as you do).  Think I tried using a `IntStream` last time I checked something like this

Comment: What exactly do you mean "not working"? Does the program quit,  generate an error, what? be specific.

Comment: What @l'L'l said. Your question is not clear. It looks like your input contains chunks separated on 3 spaces, but your regex is splitting on two. What is expected result and how actual result is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Eclipse, you can debug the code and look at the `char[]` that's backing the `String`.

Alternately, you can print the string in hex. Here is a quick and (very) dirty hex printer:

```
String s = " August 05   July 09   May 07   April 01   March 19   February 19   January 15   December 17   December 04   December 03   December 02   November 24   October 30";
for (byte b : s.getBytes("UTF-8"))
    System.out.printf("%02x ", b);
System.out.println();
for (byte b : s.getBytes("UTF-8"))
    System.out.print(b >= 32 ? (char)b + "  " : "?  ");
System.out.println();
```

*Output*

```
20 41 75 67 75 73 74 20 30 35 20 20 20 4a 75 6c 79 20 30 39 20 20 20 4d 61 79 20 30 37 20 20 20 41 70 72 69 6c 20 30 31 20 20 20 4d 61 72 63 68 20 31 39 20 20 20 46 65 62 72 75 61 72 79 20 31 39 20 20 20 4a 61 6e 75 61 72 79 20 31 35 20 20 20 44 65 63 65 6d 62 65 72 20 31 37 20 20 20 44 65 63 65 6d 62 65 72 20 30 34 20 20 20 44 65 63 65 6d 62 65 72 20 30 33 20 20 20 44 65 63 65 6d 62 65 72 20 30 32 20 20 20 4e 6f 76 65 6d 62 65 72 20 32 34 20 20 20 4f 63 74 6f 62 65 72 20 33 30 
   A  u  g  u  s  t     0  5           J  u  l  y     0  9           M  a  y     0  7           A  p  r  i  l     0  1           M  a  r  c  h     1  9           F  e  b  r  u  a  r  y     1  9           J  a  n  u  a  r  y     1  5           D  e  c  e  m  b  e  r     1  7           D  e  c  e  m  b  e  r     0  4           D  e  c  e  m  b  e  r     0  3           D  e  c  e  m  b  e  r     0  2           N  o  v  e  m  b  e  r     2  4           O  c  t  o  b  e  r     3  0
```

As you can see, the spaces are hex `20`. Hex values `00` to `1F` are control characters, like `CR` and `LF`. If your string has non-ASCII characters, then each character is printed as 2-4 bytes with hex values of `80` or higher.